# Django channels pytest testing. django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured. .

Tags: django, pytest, django-testing, django-channels, django-tests

I am getting this error when running pytest. I am following this tutorial: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

The following the things I've tried:

- place django.conf.settings.configure() at the top of the test script
- place the following code at the top of the test script

  ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(**file**) - 2

  env = environ.Env()

  env_file = str(ROOT_DIR.path('.env'))

  env.read_env(env_file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to configure pytest to configure the django settings in your pytest.ini as documented here: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
# -- FILE: pytest.ini (or tox.ini)
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings
# -- recommended but optional:
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Answer (score 11):

For all of you who haven't fixed this yet, this problem in my experience happens in one of this 3 scenarios:

- Pytest can't understand Django's structure on its own, so you'll need to `pip install pytest-django` first
- You haven't properly configured your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable on your `pytest.ini` or `setup.cfg` file
- You are running the `pytest` command on the wrong directory. Make sure you run it where your `pytest.ini`/`setup.cfg` file is